# bioinformatics sequence clustering in Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, sequence, bioinformatics

I am trying to find a new method to cluster sequence data. I implemented my method and got an accuracy rate for it. Now I should compare it with available methods to see whether it works as I expected or not.

Is it possible to tell me what are the most famous methods in bioinformatics domain and what are the packages corresponded to those methods in Python? I am an engineer and have no idea about the most accurate methods in this field that I should compare my method to them.

Comment: biopython is a library that contains a lot of algorithms for bioinformatics. Take a look there and you will for sure find something

Comment: You might consider asking your question in https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should probably explain what is your accuracy criterion. Otherwise, it may not make much sense to compare your method with others not having the same criterion.

Answer (score 2):

Two common used methods are:

- CH-hit, http://weizhongli-lab.org/cd-hit/
- Uclust (USEARCH, 32bit version is free) https://drive5.com/usearch/

Both are command line tools and written in C++ (i think)

Answer (score 2):

It also depends on the question for which tool you need(data reduction, otu clustering, making a tree, etc..). These days you see a shift in cluster tools that uses a more dynamic approach instead of a fixed similarity cutoff.
Example:

- DADA2
- UNOISE
- Seekdeep

Fixed clustering:

- CD-HIT
- uclust
- vsearch